# Trying to install PyCharm on a friend's PC but this dialog box keeps popping up and it wont detect the interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: Dialog box that keeps coming up after the "Creating virtual environment" screen]

Any solutions? I've tried reinstalling both Python and PyCharm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm : Failed to Create Interpreter Error occurred: Permission Denied - Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56789724/pycharm-failed-to-create-interpreter-error-occurred-permission-denied-windo)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney unfortunately no. When I try that and select the interpreter (python.exe from the Python directory) it gives me this dialog box. https://ibb.co/YbHmjJP . Any help?

Comment: It's apparently something to do with the --system-site-packages. I tried using python 3.7 and it brought up a similar permission denied box but with system-site-packages mentioned aswell.

Comment: Try installing the anaconda distribution for 3.7. During the installation it may ask if you want to install for yourself or everyone, only install for yourself. Then try installing PyCharm only for yourself.