# Why can't PyCharm detect an interpreter?

Tags: python, pycharm

I already downloaded both Miniconda3 and PyCharm. Since then, I'm trying to create a project in PyCharm, selecting the "New environment using" as Conda. I Choose the 3.8 Python version, I create the project and a "Failed to Create Interpreter" appears, with a bunch of code and saying some things like "InvalidArchiveError", while I literally only installed Miniconda3 in C:\ and tried to creathe the project in a folder also inside C:. Do you guys have any ideia how to solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm : Failed to Create Interpreter Error occurred: Permission Denied - Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56789724/pycharm-failed-to-create-interpreter-error-occurred-permission-denied-windo)

Comment: Depending on your Windows setup, you (or not every program you run) may not be allowed to write just everywhere on C:. Make sure you use the suggested location during installation of Python, Miniconda and PyCharm (if you don't know where you have rights exactly) and try again.